# Considering changing URL structure from example.com/page?id=1 to example.com/1/keywords but wondering what SEO impact is

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects

Currently our website has a variety of community generated content that is under the URL structure of `example.com/page?id=1`. Some of these pages rank quite well on Google due to a combination of website linking to it internally, decent content and backlinks (not sure what contributes most).

We're considering changing `example.com/page?id=1` to `example.com/1/keywords` since we've read having keywords in the URL can help with ranking and we are also making the page a level higher in the URL structure. One way to do this is to have the old page find the keywords + redirect to the new page and have `.htaccess` handle the URL change from parameters to a more SEO friendly URL.

Wondering if anyone else has made a change like this and if the multiple redirects + slower load time of querying a DB to add keywords is worth it? Is `example.com/1/keywords` much better than `example.com/1`? Also is there any impact of having all the internal links on the website point to the old link (`example.com/page?id=1`)?